# Can I change an existing partition from MBR to GPT?

Tags: linux, partition, lvm, gpt, mbr

I needed to add extra 2.5TB to the existing 400GB disk (`sda`) on my system. I added new virtual disks with 2.5TB (`sdb`), proceeded to create the partition table with fdisk.

Used `pvcreate /dev/sdb1`, to create the physical volume, then extended the volume group and finally extended the logical volume.

At the end I used the `xfs_grow2fs` for the filesystem to recognize. Only until then I realized that I only got 2TB out of the 2.5TB on the new disk due to MBR limitation.

Can I convert this drive to GPT without affecting sda? Will this movement affect the filesystem due to `xfs_grow2fs` being used? The worst case scenario would be having .5TB missing.

Using CentOS 7.

`lsblk` command output

```
NAME                 MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
fd0                    2:0    1     4K  0 disk 
sda                    8:0    0   420G  0 disk 
├─sda1                 8:1    0   500M  0 part /boot
└─sda2                 8:2    0 419.5G  0 part 
  ├─centos_sftp-root 253:0    0    15G  0 lvm  /
  ├─centos_sftp-swap 253:1    0     2G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─centos_sftp-home 253:2    0   2.4T  0 lvm  /home
sdb                    8:16   0   2.5T  0 disk 
└─sdb1                 8:17   0     2T  0 part 
  └─centos_sftp-home 253:2    0   2.4T  0 lvm  /home
sr0                   11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

`lvs` command

```
  LV   VG          Attr       LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log 
Cpy%Sync Convert
  home centos_sftp -wi-ao----  2.39t                                                    
  root centos_sftp -wi-ao---- 15.00g                                                    
  swap centos_sftp -wi-ao----  2.00g
```

`df` command

```
Filesystem                    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos_sftp-root   15G  2.7G   13G  18% /
devtmpfs                      2.9G     0  2.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                         2.9G     0  2.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                         2.9G  8.6M  2.9G   1% /run
tmpfs                         2.9G     0  2.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/centos_sftp-home  2.4T  103G  2.3T   5% /home
/dev/sda1                     497M  171M  326M  35% /boot
tmpfs                         581M     0  581M   0% /run/user/1000
tmpfs                         581M     0  581M   0% /run/user/0
```

I used `xfs_growfs` to extend home to use the additional 2.5TB but only got 2TB from the new disk due to MBR limits.

output of `fdisk -l /dev/sdb`

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 2748.8 GB, 2748779069440 bytes, 5368709120 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x3633c5d9

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048  4294967294  2147482623+  8e  Linux LVM
```

Comment: I'm confused. If you ran `pvcreate sdb` then there's neither a MBR nor a GPT on sdb. If the XFS filesystem is on a logical volume, then there's no MBR that impacts it in any way. What makes you think that your problem is related to MBR partitions? Post the output of `lsblk`, `lvs` and `df`. Also tell us exactly how you called `xfs_grow2fs` and copy-paste the output.

Comment: Output is available.

Comment: I see. You evidently didn't run `pvcreate sdb`, but `pvcreate /dev/sdb1`. Please **copy-paste the actual commands you ran**, otherwise it's hard to help you. It's also confusing that you refer to 2TB as the filesystem size, but you have a 2.4TB filesystem, your problem is the size of the _partition_ `/dev/sdb1` which doesn't span the whole disk unlike what you intended. And now post the output of `fdisk -l /dev/sdb`.

Comment: I followed the commands listed on [this tutorial](https://www.rootusers.com/how-to-increase-the-size-of-a-linux-lvm-by-adding-a-new-disk/). The only thing changing is the names of the groups displayed.

Comment: `WARNING: The size of this disk is 2.7 TB (2748779069440 bytes).
DOS partition table format can not be used on drives for volumes
larger than (2199023255040 bytes) for 512-byte sectors. Use parted(1) and GUID 
partition table format (GPT).` This is what makes me think I need to change sdb to GPT.

Comment: Edit your question to post the output of `fdisk -l /dev/sdb`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77279/discussion-between-dagonar-and-gilles).

Answer (score 4):

The MBR partition `/dev/sdb1` starts at the offset 1MB. This is good, because the first GPT partition would also start at the offset 1MB.

So delete the current partition with `fdisk` and use `g` to create a new GPT partition. Choose type LVM for this partition. **Make sure that the new partition starts at the same offset as the old one, before you use the `w` command. Otherwise you will lose all your data**.

You can now use the full extent of the 2.5TB instead of the 2TB limit on MBR. Write the changes on disk and reboot. Use `fdisk -l` to check that changes on `sdb` are okay. Now we read 2.5TB available. Time to resize the volume groups and physical volumes.

Use `pvresize /dev/sdb1` to resize to the new additional space appropriately. Afterwards use `lvresize` to resize the logical volume group. And finally `xfs_growfs` to increase the filesystem. Use `df` to confirm the changes at the end.

For this last part you may refer to [this article](https://www.rootusers.com/lvm-resize-how-to-increase-an-lvm-partition/).

Comment: This worked, not because the new disk contains no data, but because the GPT partition you created started at the same offset as the original MBR partition.

Comment: @sourcejedi The reason it worked is that the procedure actually doesn't overwrite anything in `sdb` except the partition table. Crucially, the content of the partition wasn't modified.

Comment: @Gilles I have edited for an amusing typo, and to be even more explicit about the safe sequence, and changed my downvote to upvote :).

Comment: @Gilles I reverted "Reboot the machine if you feel like it but you shouldn't need to." See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/441789/resize2fs-fail-to-resize-partition-to-full-capacity/441934#441934

Comment: @sourcejedi I think `partprobe` works in this case on modern systems, but better safe than sorry.

Comment: @Gilles I think either you're the one who is out of date, or there is some disagreement between distros :).  See comment https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/441789/resize2fs-fail-to-resize-partition-to-full-capacity/441934#comment799493_441789

Comment: I actually used `partprobe` at the end, but the system did not manage to recognize the changes and asked me to reboot afterwards.