# Ubuntu ext4 partition is not being extended or resized as expected with growpart or resize2fs

Tags: partition, resize2fs, growpart

I've previously used `growpart` and `resize2fs` to resize a mounted online ext4 paritition in a Linux system.

Currently I have a Ubuntu guest running in virtualbox that I'd like to resize the partition `/dev/sda5`. I've already extended the virtual disk on the host via `vboxmanage modifyhd --resize...`, however after running (within the guest) `growpart` I don't see any change in the partition table (I assume it's the value returned from lsblk).

```
chris@chris-VirtualBox:~$ lsblk
...
sda      8:0    0  53.9G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0  37.8G  0 part /
...
```

Resize:

```
chris@chris-VirtualBox:~$ sudo growpart /dev/sda 5
CHANGED: partition=5 start=1052672 old: size=79251456 end=80304128 new: size=111996895 end=113049567
chris@chris-VirtualBox:~$ sudo resize2fs /dev/sda5
resize2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
The filesystem is already 9906432 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!
```

`lsblk` still shows old values:

```
...
sda      8:0    0  53.9G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0  37.8G  0 part /
...
```

Is this a limitation of virtualbox? Or is there a working alternative?

---

Hmmm actually the `/dev/sda2` partition looks quite suspicious (it's size seems too large? is it overlapping with `/dev/sda5`?:

```
chris@chris-VirtualBox:~$ sudo parted /dev/sda
GNU Parted 3.3
Using /dev/sda
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) p                                                                
Model: ATA VBOX HARDDISK (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 57.9GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB   537MB   primary   fat32        boot
 2      539MB   41.1GB  40.6GB  extended
 5      539MB   41.1GB  40.6GB  logical   ext4
```

Comment: I've rebooted a few times with no change in behavior. Not sure what you mean by how do I pass the HDD to the VM? I start the VM via the virtualbox GUI.

Comment: Never mind I got it all wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The commands did not work as expected as they were contained within an extended partition as described here: https://askubuntu.com/a/365953/585364

Instead I had to first extend the `/dev/sda2` `extended` partition that was the parent of `/dev/sda5`.

So all the commands that were required  (in my specific case):

```
growpart /dev/sda 2
growpart /dev/sda 5
resize2fs /dev/sda5
```

Comment: This worked - growpart /dev/sda 2 - growpart /dev/sda 5 - resize2fs /dev/sda5